# Puiseux expansion of logarithm of lower incomplete gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, gamma-function

I'm currently exploring different methods of evaluating the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition):
$$
\gamma(s,x)=\int_0^x{t^{s-1}}e^{-t}\;\mathrm{d}t.
$$
When I look at [series representations on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%5Clog%28%5Cgamma%28100%2Cx%29%29+at+x%3D0), it returns a generalized Puiseux series expansion around $x=0$ (at least if $s$ is not too large). For example,
$$
\gamma(100,x)=\log\bigg(\frac{x^{100}}{100}\bigg) - \frac{100}{101}x + \frac{25}{520251}x^2 + \frac{550}{1804057051}x^3 + \frac{12367525}{5798643470693424}x^4 + O(x^5)
$$
This series is a complete mystery to me. How is such a thing derived? Is there a formula for generating this series for general $s$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^x{t^{s-1}}e^{-t}\, dt=\Gamma (s)-\Gamma (s,x)$$ So, around $x=0$, we have
$$I=x^s \left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{x}{s+1}+\frac{x^2}{2 (s+2)}-\frac{x^3}{6
   (s+3)}+\frac{x^4}{24 (s+4)}+O\left(x^5\right)\right)$$ that is to say
$$I=\frac {x^s}s\left(1-\frac{s x}{s+1}+\frac{s x^2}{2 (s+2)}-\frac{s x^3}{6 (s+3)}+\frac{s x^4}{24
   (s+4)}+O\left(x^5\right)  \right)$$

$$\log(I)=\log \left(\frac{x^s}{s}\right)+$$ $$\log \left(1-\frac{s x}{s+1}+\frac{s x^2}{2 (s+2)}-\frac{s x^3}{6 (s+3)}+\frac{s x^4}{24
   (s+4)}+O\left(x^5\right)\right)$$ Now, expand the logarithm to make
$$\log(I)=\log \left(\frac{x^s}{s}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^p a_n x^n$$
$$a_1=-\frac s{1+s}$$
$$a_2=\frac{s}{2 (s+1)^2 (s+2)}$$
$$a_3=\frac{(s-1) s}{3 (s+1)^3 (s+2) (s+3)}$$
$$a_4=\frac{s \left(s^3-s^2-6 s+2\right)}{4 (s+1)^4 (s+2)^2 (s+3) (s+4)}$$
and so on.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. For my future reference: the general term $a_n$ can be computed using [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version)